# Liftweb: Session Timeout not working

Tags: session-timeout, lift

I am facing problem with the session management in lift application. I am managing session using one SessionVar object which I am setting everytime I am logging in and and checking it for any application request. And it is working fine.
I have set a session timeout configuration in my web.xml file. Such that my session will expire after 5 min(inactive). 
The session timeout is working fine for first time and my session is getting expired successfully after 5 inactive min. But When I refresh(in the same browser) the page and login again, my session is not getting expire again after 5 min. Even it doesn't get expire for long.
I analysis that it was using the same JSession id which was expired earlier.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Puneet

Comment: It seems like you have verified that your Session actually is destroyed by the container, but have you tried using a `javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener` and logged that it is being properly destroyed?